# How Can One Use gcloud To Enable APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm not able to find a way to use the `gcloud` command line program to change a project's Enabled APIs. My hunch is that it's going to be in the billing "arena" but I've been trying to find this and having much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2021, it changed to

```
gcloud services list
```

[image]

Details is [here](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/list-services#enabled)

Answer (score 21):

Use

```
gcloud services enable <service name>
```

[gcloud Documentation for this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/enable)

Example:

```
gcloud services enable containerregistry.googleapis.com
```

Answer (score 7):

**Issue**
For your  current default  project do 
gcloud service-management list --enabled to list all available APIs enabled.

```
$ gcloud service-management list --enabled
Listed 0 items.
```

If you see something like the above i.e 0 items , then you most likely will be getting the error below for some commands for the project.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.machine-types.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Project {PROJECT_ID} is not found and cannot be used for API calls
```

**Solution**
What you need to do are the below

1. list the APIs available for the project that can be enabled

The output is quite lengthy so I suggest you use the global option page-size
e.g

```
$ gcloud service-management list  --available --page-size=10 --sort-by="NAME"
NAME                           TITLE
picker.googleapis.com          Google Picker API
bigquery-json.googleapis.com   BigQuery API
chromewebstore.googleapis.com  Chrome Web Store API
tracing.googleapis.com         Google Tracing API
youtube.googleapis.com         YouTube Data API v3
actions.googleapis.com         Google Actions API
dataflow.googleapis.com        Google Dataflow API
serviceuser.googleapis.com     Google Service User API
fusiontables.googleapis.com    Fusion Tables API
surveys.googleapis.com         Surveys API

NAME                                 TITLE
reseller.googleapis.com              Google Apps Reseller API
speech.googleapis.com                Google Cloud Speech API
appsmarket-component.googleapis.com  Google Apps Marketplace SDK
bigtabletableadmin.googleapis.com    Google Cloud Bigtable Table Admin API
container.googleapis.com             Google Container Engine API
vision.googleapis.com                Google Cloud Vision API
storage-api.googleapis.com           Google Cloud Storage JSON API
weavecompanion.googleapis.com        Weave Companion API
ml.googleapis.com                    Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine
firebaserules.googleapis.com         Firebase Rules API

...
```

2. Better still check specific available APIs you need 
   e.g to check for the Google Compute Engine API that I want to enable

   `$ gcloud service-management list  --available  --filter='NAME:compute*'
   NAME                              TITLE
   compute-component.googleapis.com  Google Compute Engine API`
3. Enable Billing for the project .

   `$ gcloud alpha billing accounts projects link amghouse-some-project-1  --account-id=XXFFXX-B9XX37-2D5DX --format=json
   {
     "billingAccountName": "billingAccounts/XXFFXX-B9XX37-2D5DX",
     "billingEnabled": true,
     "name": "projects/amghouse-some-project-1 /billingInfo",
     "projectId": "amghouse-some-project-1 "
   }`
4. Finally enable the api for your project

`

```
$gcloud service-management enable compute-component.googleapis.com
Waiting for async operation operations/projectSettings.c6d11ddc-915f-4d66-9b98-237e473e7682 to complete...
Operation finished successfully. The following command can describe the Operation details:
 gcloud service-management operations describe operations/projectSettings.c6d11ddc-915f-4d66-9b98-237e473e7682
```

`

5. And for good measure it won't hurt to verify

`

```
$ gcloud service-management operations describe operations/projectSettings.c6d11ddc-915f-4d66-9b98-237e473e7682 --format=json
        {
          "done": true,
          "metadata": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.api.servicemanagement.v1.OperationMetadata",
            "persisted": true,
            "resourceNames": [
              "services/compute-component.googleapis.com/projectSettings/"
            ],
            "startTime": "2017-04-08 23:30:22 WAT"
          },
          "name": "operations/projectSettings.c6d11ddc-915f-4d66-9b98-237e473e7682",
          "response": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.api.servicemanagement.v1.EnableServiceResponse"
          }
        }
```

`

**Caution**
Please note without the project being linked to a billing info , an attempt to enable the api will fail with an error similar to

```
$ gcloud service-management enable compute-component.googleapis.com
ERROR: (gcloud.service-management.enable) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Operation does not satisfy the following requirements: billing-enabled {Billing must be enabled for activation of service '' in project 'amghouse-bct-sms-1' to proceed., https://console.developers.google.com/project/amghouse-bct-sms-1/settings}
```

Comment: learned a few things about gcloud from this thorough response. thank you!

Comment: @the0ther Thanks for the feedback. Nice to know it was helpful.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but the commands need to be updated, what worked for me was: 

gcloud services enable indexing.googleapis.com
commands on this answer now provide error:
ERROR: (gcloud.service-management.list) The `service-management list` command has been replaced by `endpoints services list` and `services list`.

Comment: @FelipeValdes Thanks for the updates. One has to keep up with the release pace.

Comment: `gcloud service-management operations describe` is also been deprecated. `gcloud services operations describe operations/acf.XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX` works but does not output JSON, instead I got `Operation "operations/acf.XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" finished successfully.`

Comment: This works for me: `gcloud services list  --available  --filter='NAME:big*'`  

I guess `gcloud service-management ...` is no longer supported.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: This has been deprecated. See `gcloud services` answer.

Check out the `service-management` surface. See `gcloud help service-management` for more help, as well as `gcloud help service-management enable` for help about enabling new services. Use `gcloud service-management list` to list available services so you can find the name of the service you want to enable.

Comment: Yeah I had my eye on that one. Ok I'll dig in. Thanks!

Comment: Looking real promising. I especially like this `gcloud service-management list --available`.

Comment: `gcloud service-management` has been deprecated and split off into two separate commands now - `gcloud endpoints` and `gcloud services`. The latter (`gcloud services`) is what to use to enable/disable Google Cloud APIs for a project.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me for enabling container engine API -

gcloud services enable containerregistry.googleapis.com

Answer (score 0):

Select the project where your application will be registered (see the docs about [gcloud config set](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set))

```sh
gcloud config set project myProject
```

To see a list of available services for a project, run:

```sh
gcloud services list --available
```

Enable service in the current project (see the docs about [gcloud services enable](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/enable))

```sh
gcloud services enable my-consumed-service
```